# c# unity помогите тут юнити ошибку выдает не могу справиться

Tags: c#, unity3d

вот выдает ошибку про подключении рекламы через Advertisement помогите пожалуйста

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Говорит "Объект типа Transform был удалён, но ты пытаешься получить к нему доступ". Посмотри место в коде где произошла ошибка

Answer (score 0):

После удаления объекта, Вы пытаетесь его двигать.